# Why does Rails validate unchanged attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

It seems that validates_uniqueness_of :some_field will run on a "save" even if the some_field attribute has not changed (if other fields have changed).  This seems wasteful, since each validates_uniqueness_of will require a database call.  I know I can pass a Proc to validates_uniqueness_of to check whether some_field has changed, and I am considering going through all the validations and doing that wherever possible.  What I am wondering is:

1) Is that what people interested in performance generally do with their validations?

2) Why is it not validates_uniqueness_of's default behavior to check whether the attribute has changed first?

3) Are there good reasons for running such validations on attributes that haven't changed?

I am using Rails 2.3 (for the moment-- we are working on upgrading).  I don't know this is the same situation in Rails 3.

Comment: Regarding 2 and 3, values can be put into the database outside of the Rails application. So, a value added by another app could render your unchanged attribute invalid. In addition, your validations could evolve over time, rendering unchanged attributes invalid.

Comment: @niiru:  Thanks for taking the time to reply.  From a user's perspective, it would be really odd to edit part of a record, and then be told that another part of the record was invalid which was not edited and was logically independent from the change.  Also, in your scenario, if the rails app is enforcing uniqueness on a field, shouldn't the other application also be doing the same?

Comment: Definitely! But you may be working with a database that is tied into several applications, not all of which are as responsible about data validations as your app is...

Comment: Yes, the behavior is the same in Rails 3 _and_ rails 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if someone changed the value in the database directly?

What if some other (non rails app) app also accesses the database?

In all above scenarios you will still want that your data be valid, so that your rails application behaves as expected. In case the data was tampered with (by the other app, or in database directly), your rails app throws an error because it doesn't expect that data.

Having said that, it is the default behaviour. The default behaviour is generally more restrictive, in order to maintain data validity and minimise scope of errors, omissions, and occasional slips. In case you are worried about performance in your case, maybe your object is being updated very frequently, and you have a lengthy custom validation on a field that isn't being updated that frequently, and you don't want to run that validation each time, then it makes perfect sense to customize the default behaviour as you have described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue with a Rails 3.0 application. I solved it by checking to see if the unique attribute was edited by the user. Here's the relevant code excerpt for my User object that worked.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :email, :password, :ha1, :ha1b, :sip_username, :domain

validates :sip_username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true,
                         :unless => :update_username?,
                         :exclusion => {:in => %w(9196),
                         :message => "9196 is reserved, please choose another"}
def update_username?
  # check to see if we are updating a sip_username for an existing user
  stored_user = User.find_by_sip_username self.sip_username
  # the id of the user is the same as me and sip_username hasn't been changed. skip validations.
  if (stored_user.present?)
    stored_user.id == self.id && stored_user.sip_username == self.sip_username
  end
end
```